# xcopy - недопустимое количество параметров

Tags: windows, cmd, windows-xp

В WIndows XP пишу xcopy `Y:\Updates\Instructions %userprofile%\desktop /e /c /y /z` и выдаёт ошибку. В Windows 10 всё работает. Думаю он второй путь воспринимает как параметр.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вероятно переменная %userprofile% включает пробелы. Попробуйте заключить целевой объект в скобки:

```
Y:\Updates\Instructions "%userprofile%\desktop" /e /c /y /z
```

Comment: Уже разобрался, проблема была именно в этом.